# Restrict Search functionality to specific users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, sharepoint-search, 2019, restricted-access

I want to restrict the search feature, in a web application/site collection, to limited user. it will like I will make a SP Group and only users of that group can use search functionality and rest of the user cannot search any thing.

Currently running an environment of SharePoint 2019.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Remove/disable search box for some users? when user searches anything in SP they can only see the results they have access to.

Comment: As mentioned all search results are security trimmed so no user will see anything that they do not have access to. You could however, if your search is a webpart/add-in on a classic site, enable audience targeting and thus hide the search for everyone but a selected group.